# how to store current date+ current time in database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-1.9.2

I have a problem. I want to store current date+ time in my database. I was trying to make a migration like

> current_time:date

and

```
current_time=DateTime.now
```

but it stores current date only, also i was trying to do

```
current_time:time
```

in migration. and then

```
current_time=Time.now
```

or

```
current_time=DateTime.now
```

But it stores only current time, another parametres are 2000-01-01. What I am doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: i need to store time like timestamps in migration

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `timestamp`in your migration. Of cause `date`only stores dates and `time`only stores time but `timestamp`stores the secounds since the 01.01.1970 00:00 and that an absolute time definition.

```
current_time:timestamp
```

To add some days you can do

```
instance.current_time+=3.days
```

Comment: thanks, but if I want to renew it, what should I do? I want to renew both time and date

Comment: You mean you have an existing time in your database and want to add lets say 3 days to it? Or what exactly do you mean?